# Setting user environment variables is very slow

Tags: windows-8, powershell, environment-variables

I'm using the GitHub for Windows application. Lately I've noticed that starting a PowerShell console from within the GitHub application takes ages. After some digging I've found that the slow command is setting an environment variable. More specifically these lines in GitUtils.ps1 (part of PoshGit that GitHub uses):

```
function setenv($key, $value) {
    [void][Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($key, $value, [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Process)
    [void][Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($key, $value, [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
}
```

Setting the Process-wide variable is instant, but the User variable takes a long time. Using the following script:

```
$sw = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Horses", "are neat", [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
$sw.Stop()
$sw.Elapsed
```

I can see that this operation takes over 80 seconds. Setting a User env var using the default advanced settings window is fast. Using Rapid Environment Editor, setting a var is usually fast, but sometimes takes 5-10 seconds, but never anything as long as this.

Anyone have any suggestions to what may be causing this?

Comment: Please note that calling `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable` with the `EnvironmentVariableTarget.User` parameter will result in direct registry access (in contrast to a simple WINAPI call).

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Is there another way to set a user env var from PowerShell?

Comment: Sorry, I am not aware of any.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to Environment class sources (can be found [here](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Environment@cs/1305376/Environment@cs), line 864), after setting user/machine scope environment variable, it calls native SendMessageTimeout function to notify any process about changes in environment. Here is excerpt:

```
IntPtr r = Win32Native.SendMessageTimeout(
    new IntPtr(Win32Native.HWND_BROADCAST), 
    Win32Native.WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 
    IntPtr.Zero, 
    "Environment", 
    0, 
    1000, 
    IntPtr.Zero);
```

So 1000 milliseconds (1 second) timeout is given to any recipient to process the message. E.g. if 5 of them fail to process it, you could have up to 5 seconds delay. More about SendMessageTimeout can be found in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Interesting. Would this mean I have 80+ subscribers to that message that all let it timeout?

Comment: Apparently it's Google Chrome that's the culprit here. If I close Chrome, the operation completes in a couple of seconds. Wonder why Chrome lets those messages time out.

Comment: I guess this might require digging into Chrome code... Another idea is that Chrome application usually runs in dozens of processes, each tab and extension is in a separate one. Perhaps, the more tabs open/extensions you have, the more time it will take to process the system message.

Comment: I used an external program for my VBA app (since you can't do threads in VBA), this does work for me http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/win32/tutorials/article.php/c10849/Setting-a-System-Environment-Variable.htm