# Windows Powershell is taking long time to start the first time after Windows login

Tags: windows-7, powershell

I generally use windows powershell instead of command prompt on Windows. I have noticed that when I start it for the first time after Windows is started it takes a long time for the prompt for the commands to show up.

To take care of this problem I start it and then close it immediately and then start it again. If I do this it starts almost instantly.

Is there a way to make sure that the prompt for command comes up immediately instead of me having to do this little hack?

Comment: @DaveRook I guess I could but wouldn't that start it up at windows login automatically? I don't want that. I want to remove the delay when I start it for the first time after windows login.

Comment: @DaveRook Isn't that after a specific setting to load something was made to Powershell? I haven't done anything like that.

Answer (score 6):

PowerShell relies on the
[.NET Framework](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework), you can try updating
that. Also, I noticed a couple of problems with the script in the other answer

- `sort` is going to cause an error because not all entries have a `location`
- some systems will benefit from re`ngen`ing, which that script will never do

Here is my modified version

```sh
$Env:PATH = [Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment]::GetRuntimeDirectory()
[AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | % {
  $pt = $_.Location
  if (! $pt) {continue}
  if ($cn++) {''}
  $na = Split-Path -Leaf $pt
  Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "NGENing $na"
  ngen install $pt
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Set-Alias ngen (Join-Path ([System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment]::GetRuntimeDirectory()) ngen.exe)
[AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() |
    sort {Split-path $_.location -leaf} |
    %{
        $Name = (Split-Path $_.location -leaf)
        if ([System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment]::FromGlobalAccessCache($_))
        {
            Write-Host "Already GACed: $Name"
        }else
        {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "NGENing      : $Name"
            ngen $_.location | %{"`t$_"}
         }
      }
```

[Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2008/09/02/speeding-up-powershell-startup-updating-update-gac-ps1.aspx) --- [Download the code as ps1 file](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-components-postattachments/00-08-92-01-09/update_2D00_Gac.ps1)

> If the workstation has no direct internet access unmark this option in
>   IE: 'Check for publisher's certificate revocation' under advanced
>
> You might want to double-check and verify there are no profiles. Run
>   this command and see if any of these are true:
>
> PS S:> $profile.CurrentUserAllHosts, $profile.CurrentUserCurrentHost,
>   $profile.AllUsersAllHosts, $profile.AllUsersCurrentHost | test-path

[Source](http://www.minasi.com/forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=39253)

Quote edited slightly from original

> The problem [could be due to] slow setting of user environment
>   variables. I recently merged a change that uses a temp file instead.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507054/powershell-takes-a-long-time-to-load-on-start-up-while-loading-ssh-agent-git)

More about user environment [variables can be found here](https://superuser.com/questions/565771/setting-user-environment-variables-is-very-slow) which also suggests it could be Chrome within the comments:

> Apparently it's Google Chrome that's the culprit here. If I close Chrome, the operation completes in a couple of seconds. Wonder why Chrome lets those messages time out.
>   I guess this might require digging into Chrome code... Another idea is that Chrome application usually runs in dozens of processes, each tab and extension is in a separate one. Perhaps, the more tabs open/extensions you have, the more time it will take to process the system message.

Since your fault is about it taking a long time to load initially (but quick afterwards) try

> ...then you are seeing the time it takes to load .NET, PSH and Snapins. If not, then likely to be profile related (either PSH profile or something like contacting AD1).`

[Source](https://serverfault.com/questions/7789/why-does-powershell-take-so-long-to-init)